# Running PMD with gradle without compiling

Tags: gradle, pmd

I need to integrate PMD into the build process, so I created a file, 'check.gradle' under a separate directory and added it to the build.gradle which is a main file for the build process.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        sbDir = "${projectDir.parent}"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // maven { url: 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
    }
}

apply from: file('../build/pmd/check.gradle')
```

**check.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'pmd'
    pmd {
        consoleOutput = true
        toolVersion = "6.21.0"
        reportsDir = file("pmd/reports")
        ruleSets = ["../build/pmd/MyRuleSet.xml"]
        ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

The code base is written in Java. The problem is that I want to run it before compile happens or i don't want to run it separately as a simple task.  Our compile task is pretty complicated, cuz it depends on many libraries.

I am running as like this.

```
gradlew.bat --build-file bundles/build.gradle check
```

Is there a way to scan all the java source code (we have 200 bundles - each bundle is packaged with many java files) without compiling java source code?

Comment: You could explicitly skip those tasks adding `-x compileTaskName` arguments (for each compile task name you want to skip), but bare in mind, PMD's results will degrade from not having the complete classpath. PMD relies on being able to resolve types and bytecode in several rules, and will fallback to a "best effort" if unavailable, that may produce false positives and false negatives… Gradle is very aggressive in caching task results and doing incremental builds, I'd rather try to leverage this to speed up build and analysis.

Comment: The reason is that somehow it complains a lot of ' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:' for my java source files, even though they are not explicitly referenced in the source code. All of java sources files are into osgi bundles under 'src' directory.  Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: If running an analysis (`./gradlew pmd`) fails with such errors, report it to https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues